# How do I check who is connecting to my hotspot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, wifi-hotspot

Is there any way to check who is connecting to my hotspot? I am using a rooted Samsung Galaxy SII.

I use the SII's tethering feature in: Settings > Wireless and network > Tethering and portable hotspot > Portable Wi-Fi hotspot settings > Portable Wi-Fi hotspot to create my hotspot.