# Is there a way to check who is connected to my Galaxy Nexus hotspot

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, wifi-hotspot

I would like to be able to check who is using my phones hotspot, it was simple on my Droid 2 since the Motorola app much like the one shown in the answer to [How do I check who is connecting to my hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18529/how-do-i-check-who-is-connecting-to-my-hotspot) however I don't see a version of this screen with the galaxy nexus.

Update:
Looking for a non-root solution