# How to view who is connected to my Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, 9.0-pie

I'm using stock android 9.0. I'd like to be able to get a list of the devices (IP and/or MAC) that are connected to my phone when it's used as a Wi-Fi AP.

Here are a few ways I tried but didn't work:

- In the settings, there is an indicator of how many devices are connected (Network & internet / Hotspot & tethering / under Wi-Fi hotspot), but there is no list of them.
- Fing only works when my phone is a client on a Wi-Fi network, not when it is an AP.
- On Oreo, the  `/proc/net/arp` file used to contain the list, but as of Pie, it doesn't (it's empty, even when something is connected).

I'm looking for a solution that does not require root.

Comment: You might wish to check with: [Is there a way to check who is connected to my Galaxy Nexus hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20689/16575) // [How do I check who is connecting to my hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/18529/16575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to enter `ip neighbor` into a terminal app, it displays both the IP and the MAC address of the connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ksiri tool](http://karthiksiriapps.blogspot.com/p/ksiri-android-tools.html) to list devices connected to your hotspot.

[image: IMG:]

you can also name the device connected.
Naming is based on MAC address, so if connected device resets it's address, then you may have to name again.

I was facing same issue on my Android Oreo, some tools on net available is filled with ads or asking for unnecessary permissions or root.

Just for this simple listing of which devices are connected, ads and special permissions or rooting, not necessary, so I have created this app, which will not ask for any permissions and neither shows any ads and no need of root.

This is the first step of "Ksiri Tools" that I have created, further if any tooling things comes up, I will add to same app.

I have not released any of my apps on play store, as I feel it's unnecessary to pay Google.
You can download apk file and install. While installing you will be clearly shown by Android that this app doesn't require any permissions.
So safe to use.

Comment: Your app is buggy, it doesn't show any devices (even after pressing refresh). However I looked into the source code, and it turns out that `ip neighbor` does work, if I enter it manually in a terminal app. I will accept your answer once your app works on my phone.

Comment: @AstroRP there is already an answer with `ip neigh` was late to flag as duplicate see: [How to view devices connected to hotspot on Google Pixel?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/174728/209414)